# If $xyz=1$, find the value of $\frac{1}{1+x+y^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+z+x^{-1}}$.

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> If $xyz=1$, find the value of $\frac{1}{1+x+y^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+z+x^{-1}}$.

I am not being able to find a way to simplify further than this,
$$\frac{y}{1+y+xy}+\frac{z}{1+z+yz}+\frac{x}{1+x+xz}$$

Is there any way to factorize this?

Comment: Let $x=\dfrac{a}{b},y=\dfrac{b}{c},z=\dfrac{c}{a} \; (abc \ne 0)$, and the answer can be easily shown.

Comment: What did you try? I think there sure are some duplicate...

Comment: The quick, direct solution is using @Zerox's hint. If you don't "see" that, however, you can just substitute $\,z=\frac{1}{xy}\,$ in the expression, then simplify the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get these relations from $xyz=1$,
$$xy=z^{-1}$$
$$yz=x^{-1}$$
$$xz=y^{-1}$$
Putting these in the equation,
$$\frac{1}{1+x+y^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+z+x^{-1}}$$
$$\frac{y}{1+y+xy}+\frac{2}{1+y+z^{-1}}-\frac{1}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{1}{1+z+x^{-1}}$$
$$\frac{y}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{2}{1+y+z^{-1}}-\frac{z}{z+yz+1}+\frac{1}{1+z+yz}$$
$$\frac{y+2}{1+y+z^{-1}}+\frac{1-z}{1+z+yz}$$
$$\frac{z(y+2)}{z+yz+1}+\frac{1-z}{1+z+yz}$$
$$\frac{yz+2z+1-z}{1+z+yz}$$
$$\frac{1+z+yz}{1+z+yz}=1$$

Hope this helps.